# Using two chords and an angle to find center and radius of a circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image: Radius/Center circle problem]

Hello,

I am trying to solve the problem below. Is it possible to solve for the Center and Radius of the circle given the information provided, or is there something missing? I know how it's simple enough to calculate the radius of a circle given a chord, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about it if I don't have the height to the arc of the circle. Can I use the angle about the origin to come up with another triangle to use? That's what i was leaning towards trying.

Comment: it's not clear to me what $A_i$ represent. A point of intersection? an equation for a line?

Comment: I think A1 and A2 are line segment lengths outside the circle. I will see if I can get a clarification.